# High GPU usage and performance drop with HiDPI enabled

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, resolution

I have a macbook pro 13 2018(Iris Plus 655, quad-core) with a 2K external monitor.
But if I enable HiDPI:
[image]

there's a dramatic performance drop and high GPU usage. For example, when I'm writing code in IntelliJ Idea, the GPU usage increases to 30% ~ 50%, which is usually less than 5% with native 2K without HiDPI. In the mean time, I'm suffering from noticeable response lag and frame rate drops.

I guess the Iris Plus 655 has became a bottleneck. Can I solve this by using an eGPU(RX580)? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you enabling HiDPI on the external monitor, or the laptop screen? HiDPI is the default on Mac laptop screens, so you shouldn't expect any surge there. And HiDPI on the external should still be driving the same number of pixels. (Though I don't think it's necessary on a 2K display.) Or are you saying, essentially, that there's a GPU surge when you plug the 2k monitor in? I have an older MBP and plug it into a 2K display occasionally without observable problem.

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, I'm enabling HiDPI(120%) on the external 2K monitor, and I my GPU is heavily loaded. I've found that the rendered resolution with HiDPI enabled actually is 4096 * 2304, which is more than 4K. This can be found by clicking Preference->System Report->Display Tab